# What constraint is not correct with this inline assembly?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

I have x86 (32-bit) inline assembly in C++ code being compiled for 32-bit Linux by gcc 9.3.0. At the end of the `asm` call, I get the error `'asm' has impossible constraints`. It doesn't tell me *which* constraint(s) are "impossible" or why.

I understand the syntax of the `__asm__(...)` statement as documented [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm), and I spent some time trying to prove why each constraint is correct, but I can't figure out which constraints to add or remove, or the offending assembly that is violating a constraint.

Here's the code:

```
extern int    view_pitch;
static int    scale;
static int    rle_remainder;
static int    height;
static short *color_table;
static PIXEL *RLE_palette;
static int    repeat;
static PIXEL *dest;
static UCHAR *src;

void RLE_blit(void)
{
  __asm__ __volatile__ (
  "     mov %2, %%edi\n"
  "     push %%ebp\n"
  "     mov %3, %%edx\n"
  "mloop:\n"

  "     xor %%ecx, %%ecx\n"
  "     mov (%%edx), %%cl\n"
  "     add $0x2, %%edx\n"
  "     imul %4, %%ecx\n"
  "     add %0, %%ecx\n"
  "     xor %%eax, %%eax\n"
  "     mov %%ecx, %%ebx\n"
  "     and $0xffff, %%ecx\n"
  "     shr $0x10, %%ebx\n"
  "     mov %%ecx, %0\n"
  "     cmp $0x0, %%ebx\n"
  "     jbe mloop\n"

  // color region code
  "     mov -0x1(%%edx), %%al\n"

  "     mov %%eax, %%ecx\n"           // save orginal pixel in eax
  "     and $0x1f, %%eax\n"           // now modulo original pixel by 32 to get offset
  "     mov %5, %%esi\n"              // pointer to color table
  "     jz bypass\n"

  "     shr $0x5, %%ecx\n"            // divide pixel by 32 to get region
  "     mov (%%esi,%%ecx,2), %%cx\n"  // get region number from region array into cx
  "     shl $0x5, %%ecx\n"            // multiply by 32 to get start of region

  "     mov %6, %%esi\n"
  "     add %%ecx, %%eax\n"           // add offset
  "     mov (%%esi,%%eax,2), %%ax\n"

  "     cmp %1, %%ebx\n"              // is run length <= than remaining column height
  "     jbe no_run_len_adjust\n"      // yes: don't adjust
  "     mov %1, %%ebx\n"              // no : set run length to height

  "no_run_len_adjust:\n"

  "     sub %%ebx, %1\n"

  "     mov %7, %%ebp\n"
  "     mov %8, %%esi\n"

  "run_len_loop:\n"                   // BEGIN outer run length loop
  "     mov %%ebp, %%ecx\n"

  "col_loop:\n"                       // BEGIN inner column repeat loop
  "     dec %%ecx\n"
  "     mov %%ax, (%%edi,%%ecx,2)\n"
  "     jnz col_loop\n"               // END column repeat loop

  "     add %%esi, %%edi\n"
  "     dec %%ebx\n"
  "     jnz run_len_loop\n"           // END run length loop

  "     cmp $0x0, %1\n"
  "     jg mloop\n"
  "     jmp exit1\n"

  "bypass:\n"
  "     mov %%ebx, %%eax\n"
  "     imul %8, %%eax\n"
  "     add %%eax, %%edi\n"

  "     sub %%ebx, %1\n"
  "     cmp $0x0, %1\n"
  "     jg mloop\n"

  "exit1:\n"
  "     pop %%ebp\n"
  :"+m"(rle_remainder), "+m"(height)
  :"m"(dest), "m"(src), "m"(scale), "m"(color_table), "m"(RLE_palette), "m"(repeat), "m"(view_pitch)
  :"esi", "edi", "eax", "ebx", "ecx", "edx", "memory"
  );
}
```

Here's the rundown of why I *think* what I have is right:

- Outputs: `rle_remainder` and `height` are both read and written-to, so the `+m` is appropriate.
- Inputs: `dest`, `src`, `scale`, `color_table`, `RLE_palette`, `repeat` and `view_pitch` appear only to be read from; they aren't in the "destination" position of any instruction. So the `m` means they're being (only) read from.
- The list of clobbered registers (`"esi", "edi", "eax", "ebx", "ecx", "edx"`) contains all registers that are modified. Since some of the modified registers are 8 or 16-bit "parts" of these registers, like `ax`, these parts of the registers don't need to be explicitly specified, because the whole 32-bit register they're a part of is already being listed as clobbered.
- `"memory"` is listed as clobbered to provide a read/write barrier for memory addresses being written to, not only the memory locations of the outputs themselves. For example, `mov %%ax, (%%edi,%%ecx,2)` clobbers memory.
- I didn't use the `goto` keyword, because no **C** labels are being used -- the only labels being jumped to here are labels within this block of inline assembly.
- The frame pointer `ebp` gets modified during the course of the code, but restored at the end, so I didn't list it as clobbered. If I do list it, gcc throws an error, because you're not allowed to tell gcc that you clobbered the frame pointer anymore, I don't think. Either way, the code fails to compile with or without `ebp` called out as clobbered.
- Speculation: Could it be complaining that `ebp` gets modified *at all*? Even though we restore the value of it back to the original at the end of the code -- guaranteed -- unless the program crashes? The docs weren't clear on whether the rule is "you can't modify `ebp` *at all*, even temporarily" or "if you modify `ebp`, the value at the end of your inline asm must be restored to the original". If it's the former, then my code is wrong, because `ebp` gets modified during the execution of this code.

Clearly I am missing something about gcc's expectations of either the constraints or the assembly, but I can't spot what it is.

Comment: Make sure you are not compiling as PIE which is default nowadays on many systems. That may be using `ebx` for accessing data in 32 bit mode. By the way, I don't see anything obvious in that block that would need inline asm. The compiler should be generating good (or even better) code.

Comment: I added `-no-pie` and the error is the same. Is there another flag I should be using to tell it to not compile in PIE mode? I am not sending any flags specifying PIC or PIE.

Comment: You could try adding `-fno-pic` and/or `-fno-PIC` as well. You can also look in `gcc -v` for _"--enable-default-pie"_

Comment: `-fno-pic` fixed it. Thanks so much! Feel free to post an answer indicating such.

Comment: There's a lot wrong here. First of all, the fact that you do `xor %%eax, %%eax` inside a loop where you never otherwise make use of eax, the fact that you do `cmp` with zero followed by `jbe`, and the fact that you wrote `mov %%eax, %%ecx\n" // save orginal pixel in eax`, together indicate you don't really know assembly, and inline assembly is the worst way to learn assembly. Second, disabling position-independence makes your binary insecure, and this isn't a good enough reason to do that.

Comment: Third, even for people who do know assembly, if an entire function is assembly, it should just be written in a `.S` file, not inlined into C for no good reason. Fourth, your function looks like it could be written in C, and the compiler would probably generate better assembly than you did. (And if you're doing this to learn assembly, then we're back to "inline assembly is the worst way to learn assembly".)

Comment: I was about to make the same point.  The `cmp $0` caught my eye, as well as the lack of `movzx` when loading ecx.  My guess was that OP was re-compiling code someone else wrote.  This is one of the dangers of using inline asm.  Most people can't read it and are afraid to touch it.  So bugs, perf issues, etc never get addressed.  People do "just enough" to keep it running.

Comment: You said that you couldn’t figure out which constraint is the problem. There isn’t any particular constraint that is a problem. The problem is that you have so many clobbers that the compiler doesn’t have any registers left to use for the operands.

Comment: You asked about the usage of ebp. The compiler doesn’t look at register usage within the assembly code at all. It only looks for % to  do operand substitution (and to replace %% with %).

Comment: @prl It looks like the actual problem is that since `view_pitch` is `extern` but everything else is `static`, their relative locations aren't known at compile-time, so in position-independent code, you need two registers, one for the offset of `view_pitch` and one for the offset of everything else, and `ebp` is the only free register.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd This is code from the '90s that I am maintaining as a historical preservation project. A rewrite in Rust would bring so many advantages without any meaningful performance hit, but the fidelity of the old software would be lost. My current challenge is to keep the old software running and port it to other platforms (e.g. Linux; this originated as a Windows/MSVCRT codebase) so that the software will have a platform to run on long-term. Running without PIC "got the code to compile," but I'm now going to use C output from RetDec (a decompiler) to do a C reimplementation.

Comment: I'll start with the minimal, ugliest C code possible that's equivalent (based on the decompiled code from RetDec), then start renaming variables, then introduce enough structure for the code to be elegant. Once I've eliminated all of the assembly, it's a fairly standard C++ porting project from there. And no, I don't understand assembly at all.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I can't imagine what contortions the Visual C++ compiler and assembler have to go through to make this work in the original Intel syntax version. Presumably the Windows project builds position-dependent code, and the inline assembly syntax for Windows doesn't require any of the constraints data at all. VC++ also doesn't care if you clobber the frame pointer. Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: @allquixotic Wait, you hand-translated this from Intel to AT&T? That explains a lot of the blatant mistakes that will keep this from working right even if you do get it to compile.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Hah, no... I used [Intel2GAS](https://github.com/skywind3000/Intel2GAS) -- which is far from perfect, but much better than I could have done myself. The opcodes map 1:1 from the original Intel syntax to this, so I imagine the original code is just as bad as this. No one on our team _really_ groks assembly, so if all goes well with the decompiled C, that'll be our approach to a gradual refactor (as well as eventually modernizing the underlying graphics rendering code while still maintaining the original look and feel.)

Comment: This code looks like it's just expanding the run length encoding in a bitmap.  There are other [sources](https://www.fourcc.org/pixel-format/rgb-bi_rle8/) of information (including [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Color_table)) that describe how that works.  If asm isn't your strong suit, starting from scratch in C, then comparing the output of your code to theirs might be a more effective approach.

Comment: And [here](http://www.dirkbertels.net/computing/bitmap_decompression.php)'s some code.